# merge 2 plots (bubblechart, scatterplot) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to this and also new to **R** so i hope I provide sufficent information.
I have 2 kinds of datasets:

- 1 with temperatures,dates (more rows than the other dataset);
- 1 with buistemp,dates,bacteria and peilbuis.

I made 2 plots:

```
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=Datum,y=temperatuur,size=Bacteria,color=Peilbuis)) +
        geom_point() +
        scale_size_continuous(range=c(2,10))
```

and

`qplot(data=total,x=Datum,y=Temperatuur)+geom_line()`

That will give this:
http://puu.sh/2TTju.png

However I want to create a graph that overlays these two plots. Does anybody know how to do this properly? (everytime i try something i get: Error: Aesthetics must either be length, and/or Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show what it is that you have tried and the error that you got so people can help you more easilly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=Datum,y=temperatuur,size=Bacteria,color=Peilbuis))+
          geom_point()+
          scale_size_continuous(range=c(2,10)) +
          geom_line(data=total,aes(x=Datum,y=Temperatuur))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Roland for your suggestion. This is very helpful. http://puu.sh/2TTLH.png is what I have now. Im not sure what those thick lines are.. and how to get ridd of those.. dataset1 also contains the Peilbuis variable and Bacteria variable. If I remove these from the first dataset (the graph should take it from dataset2), then it does not work..

Comment: Oh i managed to solve it with your code. Although I had to reverse the 2 around..: 

ggplot(data=total,aes(x=Datum,y=Temperatuur))+geom_line() + geom_point(data=data,aes(x=Datum,y=buistemp,size=Bacteria,color=Peilbuis))

Comment: You could also set `size=NA, color=NA` in `geom_line` with my code.